# Error al acceder a arreglo json con php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Buen dia, cordial saludo a todos. Nuevamente paso por este espacio porque tengo un gran problema sin resolver y esta vez es basado en php, puesto que estoy iniciando en este lenguaje.

El problema consiste en que necesito retornar unos valores en formato json desde php para lo cual utilizo el método json_encode. Pero a diferencia de los métodos que uso en Java, php me retorna las claves de los valores en mayúsculas (no se si de pronto tenga algo que ver) pero al momento de intentar accederlas desde Javascript me sale el error "undefined".

Este es el json que me retorna php:
`[{"0":"13","NROCLI":"13","1":"CC","IDEPRS":"CC","2":"123","NRIPRS":"123","3":"CLIENTE","NOMPRS":"CLIENTE","4":"NUEVO CLIENTE","APEPRS":"NUEVO CLIENTE","5":"JARDINES","DIRPRS":"JARDINES","6":"123456","TELPRS":"123456","7":"13","CODDEP":"13","8":"001","CODMUN":"001","9":"cliente@dominio.com","EMLPRS":"cliente@dominio.com"}]`

Y este es mi codigo en Javascript para leer los mismos.

```js
function find() {
    var data = {
        ideprs: $('#ideprs').val(),
        nriprs: $('#nriprs').val(),
        nrousr: '',
        action: 'FIND'
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: '../../controller/ClienteManage.php',
        method: 'post',
        data: data,
        success: function (r) {
            if (r.includes('{') || r.includes('}')) {
                r = JSON.parse(r);
                cargarDatos(r);
            } else {
                unlockInputs();
            }

        }
    });
}

function cargarDatos(data) {
    $('#nomprs').val(data.nomprs);
    $('#apeprs').val(data.apeprs);
    $('#telprs').val(data.telprs);
    $('#celprs').val(data.celprs);
    $('#emlprs').val(data.emlprs);
    $('#dirprs').val(data.dirprs);
    setValueSelect('coddep', data.coddep);
    setValueSelect('codmun', data.codmun);
}
```

En realidad no se si tenga que ver el hecho de que php me retorna las claves en mayúsculas, pero es la única diferencia que noto con los json retornados cuando utilizo Java como lenguaje del lado del servidor.

Agradezco de antemano cualquier ayuda puesto que ya llevo varias horas intentando resolver este problema. Si tienes un fragmento de código que haga lo mismo, agradezco me lo compartas para aprender de uds!

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hay varios problemas: el primero es que no tienes un JSON en sí, sino un JSON que está dentro de un array (pues está entre `[]`), por tanto, debes recuperarlo leyendo el índice `0` de `r`. Por otra parte, la llamada Ajax es asíncrona, por tanto, no puedes pasar el valor de `r` a otra función, no al menos así de fácil. Para simplificar, trabaja el valor de `r` dentro del `success` mismo. Algo así: `success: function (r) { var data=r[0]; $('#nomprs').val(data.NOMPRS); //resto}`  es posible que no necesites aplicar `parse`, pero eso depende de cómo tengas configurada la respuesta en el servidor.

Comment: Muchas gracias, de verdad. Me aclaraste todo el rollo con los arreglos en json. Muchas gracias nuevamente, pude solucionar todo con tu respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

El Json que tienes es un array.  Intenta referirte a el asi:

```
$('#nomprs').val(data[0].nomprs);
```

Comment: Excelente amigo, muchas gracias!!

Comment: Si te sirvio la respuesta, marcala como correcta.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando mandas a llamar tu función `cargarDatos` podrías realizar un conosle.log de tu data `console.log(data)`, así sabrás como se están devolviendo tus datos y acceder a ellos. Js realiza distinción entre mayúsculas y minúsculas.

Así podrías acceder a tus datos.

```
function cargarDatos(data) {
    console.log(data)
    $('#nomprs').val(data.NOMPRS);
    $('#apeprs').val(data.APEPRS);
    $('#telprs').val(data.TELPRS);
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Espero sea de tu utilidad.